# upgrade mariadb 10.0.29+maria-1~jessie failed

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, mysql, mariadb

using debian 8 with mariadb repository, apt-get dist-upgrade command failed for Mariadb Packages.

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dÃ©pendances
Lecture des informations d'Ã©tat... Fait
Calcul de la mise Ã  jour... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront mis Ã  jourÂ :
  galera-3 libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common mariadb-galera-server mariadb-galera-server-10.0 mysql-common
9 mis Ã  jour, 0 nouvellement installÃ©s, 0 Ã  enlever et 0 non mis Ã  jour.
Il est nÃ©cessaire de prendre 0 o/19,7 Mo dans les archives.
AprÃ¨s cette opÃ©ration, 521 ko d'espace disque seront libÃ©rÃ©s.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] oui
PrÃ©configuration des paquets...
(Lecture de la base de donnÃ©es... 34213 fichiers et rÃ©pertoires dÃ©jÃ  installÃ©s.)
PrÃ©paration du dÃ©paquetage de .../mariadb-galera-server_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_all.deb ...
DÃ©paquetage de mariadb-galera-server (10.0.29+maria-1~jessie) sur (10.0.28+maria-1~jessie) ...
PrÃ©paration du dÃ©paquetage de .../libmariadbclient18_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_amd64.deb ...
DÃ©paquetage de libmariadbclient18 (10.0.29+maria-1~jessie) sur (10.0.28+maria-1~jessie) ...
PrÃ©paration du dÃ©paquetage de .../libmysqlclient18_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_amd64.deb ...
DÃ©paquetage de libmysqlclient18 (10.0.29+maria-1~jessie) sur (10.0.28+maria-1~jessie) ...
PrÃ©paration du dÃ©paquetage de .../mysql-common_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_all.deb ...
DÃ©paquetage de mysql-common (10.0.29+maria-1~jessie) sur (10.0.28+maria-1~jessie) ...
PrÃ©paration du dÃ©paquetage de .../mariadb-common_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_all.deb ...
DÃ©paquetage de mariadb-common (10.0.29+maria-1~jessie) sur (10.0.29-0+deb8u1) ...
dpkg: concernant .../mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_amd64.deb contenant mariadb-client-core-10.0Â :
 mariadb-client-10.0 entre en conflit avec mysql-client-core-5.5
  mariadb-client-core-10.0 fournit mysql-client-core-5.5 et doit Ãªtre installÃ©.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de l'archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_amd64.deb (--unpack)Â :
 paquets en conflit - mariadb-client-core-10.0 non installÃ©
dpkg: concernant .../mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_amd64.deb contenant mariadb-client-10.0Â :
 mariadb-client-core-10.0 entre en conflit avec mysql-client-5.5
  mariadb-client-10.0 fournit mysql-client-5.5 et doit Ãªtre installÃ©.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de l'archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_amd64.deb (--unpack)Â :
 paquets en conflit - mariadb-client-10.0 non installÃ©
PrÃ©paration du dÃ©paquetage de .../galera-3_25.3.19-jessie_amd64.deb ...
DÃ©paquetage de galera-3 (25.3.19-jessie) sur (25.3.18-jessie) ...
Des erreurs ont Ã©tÃ© rencontrÃ©es pendant l'exÃ©cutionÂ :
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~jessie_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Sorry output is in French, but the error is :

```
mariadb-client-10.0 conflict with mysql-client-core-5.5
mariadb-client-core-10.0 provide mysql-client-core-5.5 and should be installed.
```

But on my OS I don't have mysql-client packages.
Any idea on what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `backports` to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Update:

```
apt-get update
```

Install the [`mysql-client-core-5.6`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/mysql-client-core-5.6) packages:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install mysql-client-core
```

then run :

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a wrong pinning configuration which lead to package mixing between repositories.

My bad.